# Не работает notifyDataSetChanged во фрагменте после popBackStack()

Tags: java, android

После возврата фрагмента с предыдущего экрана не работает обновление адаптера, причем *тост* в `onPostExecute()` нормально срабатывает.

В чем может быть причина?

Заметил такую штуку: если полностью переназначить адаптер в `onCreateView` в `else`, все работает, правда он становится пустой, но все работает.

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    activity = getActivity();
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);

    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.screen_two, container, false);
    mImageLoader = ImageLoader.getInstance();
    mImageLoader.init(new UILsettings().getConf(this.getActivity()));

    // footer
    footer = inflater.inflate(R.layout.footer, null);
    btnLoadMore = (Button) footer.findViewById(R.id.loadMore);
    btnLoadMore.setOnClickListener(LoadMore);
    categories = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.lvCategories);
    categories.addFooterView(footer);

    if (categoryAdapter == null) {

        new LoadAllProducts("1").execute();
        categoryAdapter = new CategoryAdapter(getActivity(), list, mImageLoader);
        categories.setAdapter(categoryAdapter);

    } else {

        categories.setAdapter(categoryAdapter);
        categories.onRestoreInstanceState(state);

    }

    return rootView;
}


View.OnClickListener LoadMore = new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        new LoadAllProducts("1").execute();
    }
};

@Override
public void onPause() {
    state = categories.onSaveInstanceState();
    super.onPause();
    categories.removeFooterView(footer);
}

class LoadAllProducts extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
    private String getParams;
    private JSONArray products;
    private JSONObject json;
    private JSON jParser = new JSON();

    public LoadAllProducts(String string) {
        getParams = string;
    }

    protected String doInBackground(String... strings) {
        json = jParser.makeHttpRequest("http://url.getallcats.php", getParams);
        return null;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(String string) {
        try {
            products = json.getJSONArray("category");

            for (int i = 0; i < products.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject c = products.getJSONObject(i);

                list.add(new Construct(
                        c.getString("name"),
                        c.getString("count"),
                        c.getInt("have"),
                        "http://url.ru/img/" + c.getString("image")));
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        categoryAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Ok", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); // срабатывает
    }

}
```

Реализация адаптера `CategoryAdapter`

```
public class CategoryAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private List<Construct> list;
    private LayoutInflater inflater;
    private ImageLoader mImageLoader;

    public CategoryAdapter(Context context, List<Construct> list, ImageLoader mImageLoader) {
        this.list = list;
        this.inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        this.mImageLoader = mImageLoader;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return list.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return list.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        ViewHolder holder;

        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_category, null);
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            convertView.setTag(holder);
            holder.ImageProductView = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.ImageProductView);
            holder.tvPost = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvPost);
            holder.productId = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        holder.tvPost.setText(list.get(position).getCategoryTitle());
        holder.productId.setText(list.get(position).getProductId());

        // IMAGE LOADER
        mImageLoader.displayImage(list.get(position).getProductImage(),
                holder.ImageProductView, null, new ImageLoadingListener() {

                    final List<String> displayedImages = Collections.synchronizedList(new LinkedList<String>());

                    @Override
                    public void onLoadingComplete(String imageUri, View view, Bitmap loadedImage) {
                        if (loadedImage != null) {
                            ImageView imageView = (ImageView) view;
                            boolean firstDisplay = !displayedImages.contains(imageUri);
                            if (firstDisplay) {

                                displayedImages.add(imageUri);
                            } else {
                                FadeInBitmapDisplayer.animate(imageView, 200);
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onLoadingCancelled(String uri, View view) {
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onLoadingStarted(String uri, View view) {
                        FadeInBitmapDisplayer.animate(view, 0);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onLoadingFailed(String uri, View view, FailReason fail) {

                    }

                });
        return convertView;
    }

    private class ViewHolder {
        public ImageView ImageProductView;
        public TextView tvPost;
        public TextView productId;
    }
}
```

А также `Construct`

```
public class Construct {

    // товар
    private String productTitle;
    private String productId;
    private String productImage;
    private int productRating;

    // категория
    private String categoryTitle;

    public Construct(String title, String id, int rate, String image) {
        this.productTitle = title;
        this.productId = id;
        this.productImage = image;
        this.productRating = rate;
        this.categoryTitle = title;
    }

    // товар
    public String getProductTitle() {
        return productTitle;
    }

    public String getProductId() {
        return productId;
    }

    public String getProductImage() {
        return productImage;
    }

    public int getProductRating() {
        return productRating;
    }

    // категория
    public String getCategoryTitle() {
        return categoryTitle;
    }
}
```

Comment: покажите реализацию конструктора `CategoryAdapter`

Comment: @SorryForMyEnglish Добавил `CategoryAdapter` и `Construct`, в адаптере тоже проблема может быть? До смены фрагмента туда и обратно все отлично работает..

Comment: Добавьте для адаптера метод добавления элементов и работайте с ним. Чета мне кажется после восстановления `list` адаптера и `list` фрагмента разные объекты

Comment: @SorryForMyEnglish Я не совсем понимаю что вы говорите, я только недельку с приложениями вожусь, до этого php и js. 

Мне все равно кажется что проблема в другом, эта же конструкция отлично срабатывает если делать полностью активити а не фрагменты, только там не приходится применять `onRestoreInstanceState(state)`, т.к. там и так все сохраняется, может это быть причиной некой "заморозки"?

Comment: Зачем вы вручную вызываете onSaveInstanceState / onRestoreInstanceState и сохраняете состояние в state?

Comment: Да, я уже заметил что это необязательно..

Answer (score 1):

Если вам каждый раз необходимо загружать в адаптер данные, то перенесите их из onCreateView в onResume:

```
@Override 
public void onResume(){
super.onResume();
 new LoadAllProducts("1").execute();
        categoryAdapter = new CategoryAdapter(getActivity(), list, mImageLoader);
        categories.setAdapter(categoryAdapter);
}
```

Comment: Нет, данные загружать не нужно, только по нажатию на кнопку, и после возврата с другого фрагмента, адаптер восстанавливает свои позиции и кол-во элементов, но, почему-то больше не подгружает данные, вернее подгружает(наверно так как _тост_ срабатывает), но адаптер не обновляется.